# Update the lable text in mobile application(CF)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have two forms,`form1` and `form2`.In `form2` i am using a thread to do some task.

form2:

```
private void Cleanup()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread Writeevent = new System.Threading.Thread(WriteOutEvents);
            Writeevent.IsBackground = true;
            Writeevent.Start();           
        }
private void WriteOutEvents()
        {
         //some code
         refresh_label();
         }
```

In form1,i have a label with count.I need to update the count in form1 after completing the thread process in form2.

form1:

```
internal void refresh_label()
        {
            //other code 
            string[] eventFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName);
            unsubmitted_label.Text = unSubmitted + eventFiles.Length;
            unsubmitted_label.Refresh();
        }
```

It is calling the `refresh_label()` function in thread but the value is not updating.

I tried with below one,which also not working

```
 unsubmitted_label.Invoke(new Action(() => unsubmitted_label.Text = "unSubmitted"));
```

I need to update my label count in `form1` after completing the process in thread in `form2`.Is it possible to update the form1 UI from form2.

Answer (score 0):

An important point to note is that you must call `Application.DoEvents()` in your code if you are `updating the UI in the worker thread`. Calling Application.DoEvents() will make sure that any events raised by the worker thread are processed by the UI thread.

[Microsoft .NET Compact Framework Multi-threading Tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446540.aspx)